# Need to tell blender developers to add different symbols in future updates

Tags: discussion

I am in need of letters which are not in the standard English alphabet. I personally am after the ancient Hebrew alphabet from the times new roman font file. I am not able to copy these letters from character map app and paste them into my blender project.

I know that, in mentioning this, I am also aware that there are many users from around the world that may be using blender, however, but do not write in European languages (for e.g. Russian, Mandarin, and Arabic to name a few).

As a solution to this I strongly propose and believe that it is paramount that the next future update of blender needs to implement allowing the default microsoft character map to show up somehow in blender, OR, for blender to have its very own (extremely extensive) character map that allows all users to have all letters and symbols of all the languages ever recorded in existence.

Where else can I better give this feedback other than this site?

I need the traditional Hebrew letters in the Times New Roman font to preferably be in my project as added text OR, in the meantime, if anyone can show me a versatile practical way of showing me how to get these symbols (as 3D objects only) into blender in a way that I can make them look bright, presentable and, mystical.

Comment: From the *how to get these symbols (as 3D objects only)* I suppose you want to create 3D text object with using non-standard font. In this case this is not a question to Blender developers rather to fonts used by Blender. In text object properties choose a font which supports those symbols, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6920/1245 for more (comments as well).

Answer (score 3):

For giving feedback to developers, see:

- [Best Place to put Feature Requests?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1190/599)
- [Best place to put bug reports?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/599)

However, an important step in that process is checking if the feature you seek doesn't already exist, perhaps in an unexpected form. At least in this case, it seems like it does: [How can I add text in a non-english language?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3522/599)